# Procedure to purchase Twilio phone number for OpsGenie Incoming call routing integration

Tags: opsgenie

What is the procedure to purchase Twilio phone number for OpsGenie Incoming call routing integration? What parameters should be considered during the purchase? As per Atlassian support, we want to purchase a custom number in US 1 region.

My requirement is to recevie call on US 1 region phone number and to route calls to India mobile numbers.

Did not try anything as I dont have a custom phone number.